# AWS EFS - Can we install software on it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-efs

I know that AWS EFS is a shared space for keeping files to be accessed from multiple EC2 instances.

From my understanding, AWS EFS is block based storage. So can we install software or OS on it?

Just a thought. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: *"AWS EFS is block based storage."*  That is EBS, not EFS.  EFS exposes an NFS filesystem.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot : Yes, you are correct. Nowhere in the AWS Docs EFS is mentioned as block based storage. Its referred as File storage. However my query is can we install software on it? Please do let me know.

Comment: EFS isn't a server -- it's a filesystem that can be mounted to your EC2 instances, allowing them to read and write the files stored there -- so whether or not you can "install" software on EFS depends on your definition of "install."  Can you clarify?

Comment: I was looking for installation of Software. Ok let me ask in this way.. can  we install Software on EFS like we install it on EBS which has some OS? Ex: install httpd  and deploy a application.. maybe the right way to look at my question is Can we install OS in EFS and install Software on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use EFS the same way you'd use any NFS share, which means that anything reading or writing standard files can use EFS in the same way you'd use an EBS volume -- except that the EFS filesystem can be mounted to multiple instances at the same time, while EBS volumes cannot.

What you can't do is boot an EC2 instance from EFS, so installing the OS on an EFS filesystem would not work.

Answer (score 2):

> From my understanding, AWS EFS is block based storage. So can we install software or OS on it?

For the software - if you mount EFS as a filesystem, effectively you may store anything on it. If you install an application on the EFS-backed filesystem, it will run from it. Or rather - the application binaries and files will be read from EFS.

On the other side - it is not the fastest storage option. IMHO it is VERY slow and the speed is depending on amount of stored data or the provisioning option.

So it is possible, but the question is if it is feasible..

For the OS - EFS to be mounted requires already running Linux OS, so I don't thing it very feasible. Maybe if you describe your use case in details, someone could provide better information

Comment: Thanks for the reply @gusto2 .. I don't have any use case for this. I was just reading about it, and just had a thought. If its possible, please provide me some documentation. I may find use case probably after reading about it in details somewhere.

Comment: Hi, @gusto2 I have a use case in mind....can i run tensor flow based machine learning applications or python applications...inference or training models with efs or should i consider ebs or something else for that because i want to access my files from two different ec2 instances so i only use gpu instance when needed for machine learning or else use t2 for file editing to reduce costs

Comment: +1 for "it is not the fastest storage option." I have miniconda on it and it works, but you will be waiting for a while when creating an environment.